# programatically add button click in winforms?

Tags: winforms, events, event-handling

is it possible to add button click event? i want to add controls dynamicly but i don't bind event's to my controls.

```
    this.buttonDeneme = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.buttonDeneme.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 90);
    this.buttonDeneme.Name = "button1";
    this.buttonDeneme.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(122, 23);
    this.buttonDeneme.TabIndex = 0;
    this.buttonDeneme.Text = "FileUpload";
    this.buttonDeneme.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.buttonDeneme.Click += ????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dotTutorial answer is going to work but lot's people still have difficulty with Linq and Lambda expression so if you don't understand it the very basic way to write this is :

```
this.buttonDeneme.Click += new EventHandler(MyCustomClickHandler);

void MyCustomClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do whatever you want here
}
```

but creating multiple button is usually because they wont do the same exact thing so you might want to set the `this.buttonDeneme.Tag` to some sort of identifier. i prefer using string in there.

then in the click event you can retrieve that value and know what to do. here a corrected version with the Tag used :

```
this.buttonDeneme.Tag = "SearchBook";
this.buttonDeneme.Click += new EventHandler(MyCustomClickHandler);

void MyCustomClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // for button created above the value when 
   // the click is called will be "SearchBook"
   string sTag = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();

   if(sTag == "SearchBook")
   {
       // do stuff for search book
   }
   else if(sTag == "blablabla")
   {
       // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest alternative would be to use a lambda expression.

```
this.buttonDeneme.Click += ((s, e) => {
// The code that handles a click event
});
```

's' will be the sender object and 'e' the eventargs.